# Unable to send curl to test the user agent

Tags: php, .htaccess, curl, cakephp-2.0, user-agent

I'm trying to see if the following code in htaccess in Cakephp2 is working to block the SemrushBot.
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "SemrushBot"   Access

I want to test on my local server by sending a SemrushBot to my site with the following crl command.

```
curl -k --head -H 'User-agent: SemrushBot' https://192.xxx.xx/mysamplesite.com
```

After using the above command, I get the following result. It seems like it has been requested but the problem is I'm not getting the error log.
The error log should contain "File does not exist" & "client denied by server configuration" because the SemrushBot was attempting to access my site.
I believe that the error log should show in Cakephp2's tmp/logs/. Some tips and examples would be great. I would love to hear from you.

```
Date: Mon, 05 Jun 2017 09:44:33 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Location: https://192.xxx.xx/mysamplesite.com
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

Comment: How does the rest of your directives or rules look like? `SetEnvIfNoCase` sets an environment variable, nothing more. It doesn't allow or deny anything.

Comment: Well , actually there is a logic behind it to deny the variables I set. What I want to do is send the dummy SemrushBot to my site with curl.

Comment: I just saw your other question. It seems the other question and this one are related to the same problem. Even, if you don't get an answer or comment to the previous one, it is better to update and improve the previous question, because then all relevant information is in one place, and you might even get an answer.